# Scrollable table having a redraw issue. Doesnt seem to be clearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a scrollable table. 
In each cell I draw 3 UILabels. The first few cells draw ok. But as I scroll down the table the UILabels seems to be drawing over previous UILabels. Its like the Labels in the cell have an old label already there that was cleared. I could probably fix this by drawing a background color over the whole cell each redraw, but that still doesn't explain this strange problem and why its happening.

Anybody know why this occurs and what a solution might be?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

Match *aMatch = [appDelegate.matchScoresArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel * teamName1Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5, 100, 20)];
teamName1Label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
teamName1Label.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
teamName1Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
teamName1Label.text = aMatch.teamName1;
[cell addSubview:teamName1Label];

UILabel *teamVersusLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,5, 40, 20)];
teamVersusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
teamVersusLabel.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
teamVersusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
teamVersusLabel.text = @"V";
[cell addSubview:teamVersusLabel];


UILabel *teamName2Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155,5, 100, 20)];
teamName2Label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
teamName2Label.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
teamName2Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
teamName2Label.text = aMatch.teamName2;
[cell addSubview:teamName2Label];

return cell;
}
```

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution for this problem is to define these labels in the 
**-(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**  method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier]autorelease];

UILabel * teamName1Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5, 100, 20)];
teamName1Label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
teamName1Label.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
teamName1Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
teamName1Label.text = aMatch.teamName1;
teamName1Label.tag = 1;
[cell.contentView addSubview:teamName1Label];
[teamName1Label release];

UILabel *teamVersusLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,5, 40, 20)];
teamVersusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
teamVersusLabel.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
teamVersusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
teamVersusLabel.text = @"V";
teamVersusLabel.tag = 2;
[cell.contentView addSubview:teamVersusLabel];
[teamVersusLabel release];


UILabel *teamName2Label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155,5, 100, 20)];
teamName2Label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
teamName2Label.textColor =  [UIColor redColor];
teamName2Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
teamName2Label.text = aMatch.teamName2;
teamName2Label.tag = 3;
[cell.contentView addSubview:teamName2Label];
[teamName2Label release];

return cell;
}
```

Now the cellForRowAtIndexPath method will be--

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell=nil; 

    static NSString *Identifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
    if(cell == nil){
    cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:Identifier withIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    Match *aMatch = [appDelegate.matchScoresArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = aMatch.teamName1;

    label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = @"V";

    label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    label.text = aMatch.teamName2;

    return cell;
    }
```

Just try this code..Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a cell re-use issue.  The code is adding the labels to the cell every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called (even if cell is not nil).

When you scroll, a previous cell that already has the labels is loaded and then the code adds new labels over the old ones.

Only create and add the labels to the cell in the `if (cell == nil)` section.  When creating the labels, set tags on the labels.

Then outside the `if`, retrieve the labels using their tag using `viewWithTag` and set their text.