# UITableViewCell Problem

Tags: iphone, ios4

i am creating a Custom reusable UITableViewCell with Three labels and one imageView,and i am removing them in cell's dealloc method...
all is working fine but the problem **is the text in cell getting Dark while selected...
it and it is kind of overlapping on each other**
help me to avoid that problem...

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
{
    NSLog(@"Address for cel called");
    NameLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,140,20)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:NameLbl];
    NameLbl.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:15];
    NameLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    NameLbl.opaque=YES;
    NameLbl.tag = 1001;

    AddressLbl  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,25,140,20)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:AddressLbl];
    AddressLbl.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:15];
    AddressLbl.opaque=YES;
    AddressLbl.tag = 1002;

    CityStateZipLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,50,150,20)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:CityStateZipLbl];
    CityStateZipLbl.opaque=YES;
    CityStateZipLbl.tag = 1003;
    CityStateZipLbl.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:15];

}
return self;
}



- (void)dealloc {
[CityStateZipLbl release];
[NameLbl release];
[AddressLbl release];

[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Balu, for this question you can refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441579/scrollable-table-having-a-redraw-issue-doesnt-seem-to-be-clearing/4446714#4446714

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@balu :

I think what you trying to say is that when you select a cell the text color of the Label remains black it doen't change to white ?

If you want to configure highlighted state then

for UILabel use

UILabel *label;

[label setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Otherwise you can upload a screen shot for it :) ..